# An error occurred while retrieving data from "". Administrators, see the server log for more information

Tags: sharepoint-online, bcs, external-data-column

In my list, i used an external data column.
but i get this error when I try to retrieve the list of `Investment manager`.
[image]

How i can fix that please?

Answer (score 0):

This is security/Permission issue. Here is the resolution for you:

- Navigate to SharePoint admin center.
- Click on BCS settings.
- Click on Manage BDC Models and External Content Types.
- Look out for your required BDC Model and then select Set Metadata
  store permissions to Execute for all the membership groups.
- Click on Secure Store Settings.
- Select the required Target Application ID.
- Click Edit and Add the required groups. For example (Everyone except
  external users) to Target members group.

This will resolve your permission issue and you can select your external fields
[Source](http://www.letsharepoint.com/how-to-resolve-an-error-occurred-while-retrieving-data-from-administrators-see-the-server-log-for-more-information-in-sharepoint-online/).

Comment: I'm working on sharepoint 2013. I checked my permissions but they are correct! i set them to Execute.

Comment: did you check this https://littletalk.wordpress.com/2011/08/18/external-content-type-an-error-occurred-while-retrieving-data-from-a-system-administrators-see-the-server-log-for-more-information/

Comment: It's a list not a document library..even in the list settings i don't have this option or similar

Comment: have you checked this throttling issue blog: https://lightningtools.com/bcs/business-connectivity-services-end-user-implications-part-one-threshold-limit-errors/